# Fishbase-API get-query

Tags: api, get

I would like to use the `Fishbase-API` in my app.
https://fishbase.ropensci.org/

here is the README for the API...
https://fishbaseapi.readme.io/reference/getting-started

But I don't know how to create a correct query to search for certain “common names” (comnames) and get a list of results?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've tried a number of requests using their `curl` examples and in swift with the url you show,
     but I always get a `Access Denied` response. The docs says there
     is no authentication required. Is there a demo apikey that can be used to test the api
     and try to answer your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

sadly I got this response on another forum:
https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/query-for-fishbase/3359/3

Comment: Don't add screenshots to answers. The link and a short description from your side is fine.